# Arabic letter response in android studio profiler strange characters

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I'm using the profiler to view a network request but it shows me strange characters, Note that the same response is working fine in postman and even I have no problem viewing in the android app or in the logcat.

The characters are originally Arabic.

I have tried to play with the encoding in `Editor > File Encoding` without luck

[image]

```
  {
      "id": 1018070,
      "city": {
        "id": 1016766,
        "name": "Ø§Ù„Ø±ÙŠØ§Ø¶"
      },
      "name": "Ø±Ø­Ù„Ø© Ù…Ù…ÙŠØ²Ø© Ù„Ù„Ù�Ø¶Ø§Ø¡ Ø§Ù„Ø®Ø§Ø±Ø¬ÙŠ",
```